# Trick checkdnsrr in the dev environment

Tags: php

We use Vagrant to spin-up dev environemnt VMs. Within our VM infrastructure we have /etc/hosts setup to emulate our production urls. For example, if an app lives in production at https://foo.bar.com, then in our VM environment it is https://test-foo.bar.com. This has been working well but I recently hit a hiccup.

We use Symfony2, and have a field with a Url constrant and checkDNS set to true. That fires of a validator that runs the following.

```
if (!checkdnsrr($host, 'ANY')) {
```

Since this is actually reaching out to the DNS server for answers, and it of course knows nothing of my /etc/hosts file, and https://test-foo.bar doesn't really exist, this fails.

Is there an easy way to configure the VM so that this works, short of setting up a DNS server and pointing all the VMs to use it?

The VMs are running Ubuntu GNU/Linux.

Comment: Just a suggestion. How about creating a custom validator just for DEV env and hardcoding there what you need? Not exactly the perfect solution but could work just for DEV env.

Comment: I'll probably just have to disable the validator while doing my dev work.

Comment: No, you don't have to do it. You can have a different validator for DEV environment that will behave like you need it. It is just a matter of correct usage of DI based on environment.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I'll give that a shot.